# HTTP request refactoring

Tags: c#, refactoring, dotnet-httpclient

I have several open source libraries that I've written from scratch or contributed to that use the same format for generating HTTP requests to an API entry point. Currently they're written as follows:

```
    private string _apiExtension = $"&appid={_apiKey}";
    private string _apiEntryPoint = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";

    public static string GenerateWebRequest(string conn)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(conn))
            {
                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    return webClient.DownloadString(conn);

                }
            }

        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Used to generate the HTTP request and return the JSON response.

I'm then building the `conn` like so:

```
string queryByPoint = _apiEntryPoint + $"weather?lat={latitude}&lon={longitude}" + _apiExtension;
```

which would look something like:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={latitude}&lon={longitude}&appid={_apiKey}
```

with `_apiKey` and `_apiEntryPoint` being strings that are initialised in the constructor for the library.

Is there a better way of doing this? On a small scale, building a connection string isn't exactly taxing but I feel like code repetition and using 4 lines of code to build a single URL is probably excessive.

Comment: What are the 4 lines of code that get duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how [Flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) can help here (disclaimer: I'm the author):

```
var queryByPoint = _apiEntryPoint
    .AppendPathSegment("weather")
    .SetQueryParams(new { lat = latitude, lon = longitude, appid = _apiKey });
```

Flurl's primary goals are to enable [building URLs in fluent, structured way](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-url/) (grab just the [core package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl/) if that's all you need), and fluently calling those URLs and deserializing the response in about as few keystrokes as humanly possible (grab [Flurl.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/) for all the bits). Much effort has been put into enabling [testability](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/testable-http/), [extensibility](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/extensibility/), and [cross-platform support](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/installation/), all of which I believe make it ideal for API wrapper libraries.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Looks like exactly what I've been looking for, thanks!